# Configuring OpenAM with Tomcat Agent

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, openam

I have a basic question in OpenAM while creating Agent profile for J2EE before we install and Configure the Tomcat Agent.

In Agent profile we have "Agent URL". What does Agent URL mean here?

The syntax given in Agent profile page is "protocol://host:port/deploymentUri e.g. http://agent1.sample.com:1234/agentapp"

Here what agentapp means? Is it default one or our deployment application in Tomcat?

Please clear my doubts.

Thanks,
Karthick

Answer (score 1):

The "agentapp" is part of the J2EE agent ; you have to deploy it on the J2EE container. Apart other things it's responsible for handling CDSSO and notficiations.

Comment: Just as a sidenote here I'd mention that if you install the Tomcat agent with global web.xml modifications (installer will ask you), then there is no need to deploy the agentapp.war from the etc folder.

Answer (score 0):

Agent URL is the URL to the server you want to protect plus "agentapp".  When you install the J2EE agent app on the J2EE server you want to protect, it will automatically place a agentapp file in the deployments/webapps directory. Hence, if your server is at example.com, the Agent URL is:  http://www.example.com:443/agentapp (or https depending on whether you're using SSL or not).

Here is a procedure for installing the agent on the server you want to protect: http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/jee-install-guide/